# Flask pass data to child template

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, flask, jinja2

I would like to have a slightly different navbar depending on whether or not a user is signed in. Additionally, the content of dropdown menus will depend on the user that is logged in.

`views.py` file:

```
@app.route('/table')
def my_table:
    return render_template("table.html",
                            user = user,
                            my_names = my_names)
```

A page in the application (`/table`):

```
{% extends "navbar.html" %}
{% block content %}
<html> A bunch of stuff </html>
```

The simplified navbar template:

```
{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}
{% block navbar %}
    <html>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#"> Signed in as: {{ user }} </a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            {% for name in my_names %} 
                <li><a href="#"> {{ name }} </a></li>
            {% endfor %}
     </html>  
{% endblock %}
```

I would like to pass `user` and `my_names` to the navbar template. These two data change depending on who is signed in.

Am I thinking about this correctly? Is my structure ok? Should I be using something to simplify this (like `Blueprints`)?

(I know that I can get the user part by `g.user` since its global across templates)

Comment: Have you tried this? What problems are you running into?

Comment: @dirn not sure what you are asking. I am wondering how to pass data to a child template. Problem I am running into is not knowing how to do it

Comment: I'm asking if you've tried anything yet and if so what problems are you running into.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already setting the user on `g` you have most of what you need already.  The only thing left is to set the menu correctly.

The simplest thing to do is to use a [context processor](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.context_processor):

```
@app.context_processor
def provide_menu():
    menu = derive_menu_from_global_user()
    return {'menu': menu}
```

Then every template will have access to a `menu` variable containing a list of names that you can iterate over.